# count numbers in column not duplicates

Tags: xls, xlsx

I have an XL file with about 5500 lines. One column is all numbers with many repeats like zip codes. How can I count how many numbers are in that column but eliminate duplicates. For example, maybe there are only 250 zip codes in the column. How can I count that?

Comment: What have you tried? Check out this Microsoft article: [count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range-HP003056118.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Select your column then go to Data -> Additional: then select 'copy result to another column', select result position and check 'Only UNIQUE records', it will copy unique records to selected colunm.
Now you can just select all this column and look how much records there are.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is do it in steps.

First grab that whole column of values.  Dedupe it.  Paste it into it's own column.
Then down the line, put in this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(F18:F27,G18)
```

where f18:f27 is the range to check, and g18 is the number to check for.  Copy that formula all the way down the list of unique values.